# What are 'is' statements in D?

Tags: traits, d

Inside the `std.traits` module, I can find a line similar to:

```
assert(is(Unqual!(int) == int));
```

I know that `Unqual` removes any type modifiers like immutable, but what does the 'is' do? How is it different from an if statement and when should it be used?

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes. This sounds like a legitimate question. If you downvoted, please explain why.

Comment: @deadalnix I'm assuming it was downvoted because it was available in the documentation. Everyone has to admit though, that Googling is together with the letter D isn't the easiest thing to get meaningful results for.

Comment: Use "dlang", "D programming" or "site:dlang.org" for better results.

Comment: @CyberShadow I'm actually amazed it pops up 1st result with `is site:dlang.org`. It's just coincidence though. :P

Comment: I don't think that's a coincidence, considering that Google evaluates the text used in links to a page.

Comment: @CyberShadow It pretty much highlighted all `is` except the relevant ones, and in an anonymous session the page only pops up as the 7th result.

Comment: Can't reproduce the anonymous session experiment. Shows up 1st place for "dlang is" and "site:dlang.org is".

Comment: Not long ago Google started tracking your searches while anonymous as well, so that might be it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`is(Unqual!(int) == int)` is an expression, not a statement. The line you posted does not exist in `std.traits`.

I assume you mean the following line:

```
static assert(is(Unqual!int == int));
```

See the documentation for [IsExpression](http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression).

Comment: Ah no wonder I couldn't find it inside the statement documentations. :S

Answer (score 5):

`is` is an expression that allows for example to check if types are equal, if 1 type is subtype of another or if `T` a class/enum/struct etc.

The code you posted checks if specified type does not have any modifiers.

For more information se [D Language Documentation about IsExpression](http://dlang.org/expression#IsExpression).